# Can someone help me with a syntax error in python?

Tags: python, syntax

Im having an error saying: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
python3 exited with code 1...

I have a basic print statement where the error is showing.

The error appears to be at the 't' in print.

This is the code that I wrote where the error is appearing:

```
import random

intro = input("Welcome to Juni Archery, prepare your bow!") 
bullseyecounter = random.randint(int("X") (int("O"))

for v in range(5)
  for k in range(1, 5)
    for i in range(1, 5)
      error code: print("Round " + str(k) + " arrow " + str(i) + " : " )

Line 10
```

Comment: Count your parentheses in the line `bullseyecounter = ...`

Comment: I think the error is actually your missing colon `:` after your `for` statements. `for v in range(5):`*

Comment: When I add the colons its giving me this error: 
File "main.py", line 7
    for v in range(5):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
python3 exited with code 1...

Comment: ```int('X')```. You are trying to convert ```character``` to ```int```. That's an Error too.

Comment: No one actually answered my original question about the syntax.

Comment: What do you expect `random.randint(int("X") (int("O"))` to do? That's wrong on different levels. And then you forgot all the colons `:` at the end of your `for` lines.

Answer (score 1):

**First problem :**

```py
bullseyecounter = random.randint(int("X") (int("O"))
```

I don't know what do you want to do but you're trying to convert strings (X and O) to integers, you could do it if you were using numbers, but not with letters ! ( int("4") would convert the string "4" to the interger 4, but this isn't possible with letters !

---

**Second problem :**

This is just a synthax error

```py
for v in range(5)
  for k in range(1, 5)
    for i in range(1, 5)
```

Don't forget the ":" at the end of each for loops !

The correct synthax is this one:

```py
for v in range(5):
  for k in range(1, 5):
    for i in range(1, 5):
      print("Round " + k + " arrow " + i + " : " )
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some modifications to your code. The error is in line 4, see this [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) for details.

```
import random

intro = input("Welcome to Juni Archery, prepare your bow!")
number = input("enter a number here : ")
number2 = input("enter second number : ")
bullseyecounter = random.randint(int(number), int(number2))

for i in range(5):
    for k in range(1, 5):
        for i in range(1, 5):
            print(f"Round {k} arrow {i} : ")
```